# Particle system design using Three.js and Shader

Tags: three.js, vertex-shader

I'm very new to this community. As i'm asking question if there is something i claim not right, please correct me.

Now to the point, i'm design a particle system using Three.js library, particularly i'm using **THREE.Geometry()** and control the vertex using shader. I want my particle movement restricted inside a box, which means when a particle crosses over a face of the box, it new position will be at the opposite side of that face.

Here's how i approach, in the vertex shader:

```c
uniform float elapsedTime;

        void main() {
            gl_PointSize = 3.2;
            vec3 pos = position;

            pos.y -= elapsedTime*2.1;

            if( pos.y < -100.0) {
                pos.y = 100.0;
            }



            gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(pos, 1.0 );
        }
```

The ellapsedTime is sent from javascript animation loop via uniform. And the y position of each vertex will be update corresponding to the time. As a test, i want if a particle is lower than the bottom plane ( y = -100) it will move to the top plane. That was my plan. And this is the result after they all reach the bottom:

Start to fall

[image: Start to fall]

After reach the bottom

[image: After reach the bottom]

So, what am i missing here?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it, using `mod` function:

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, innerWidth / innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 300);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialis: true
});
renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

var gridTop = new THREE.GridHelper(200, 10);
gridTop.position.y = 100;
var gridBottom = new THREE.GridHelper(200, 10);
gridBottom.position.y = -100;
scene.add(gridTop, gridBottom);

var pts = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  pts.push(new THREE.Vector3(Math.random() - 0.5, Math.random() - 0.5, Math.random() - 0.5).multiplyScalar(100));
}
var geom = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(pts);
var mat = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
  size: 2,
  color: "aqua"
});
var uniforms = {
  time: {
    value: 0
  },
  highY: {
    value: 100
  },
  lowY: {
    value: -100
  }
}
mat.onBeforeCompile = shader => {
  shader.uniforms.time = uniforms.time;
  shader.uniforms.highY = uniforms.highY;
  shader.uniforms.lowY = uniforms.lowY;
  console.log(shader.vertexShader);
  shader.vertexShader = `
    uniform float time;
    uniform float highY;
    uniform float lowY;
  ` + shader.vertexShader;
  shader.vertexShader = shader.vertexShader.replace(
    `#include <begin_vertex>`,
    `#include <begin_vertex>
      
      float totalY = highY - lowY;
      transformed.y = highY - mod(highY - (transformed.y - time * 20.), totalY);
    `
  );
}
var points = new THREE.Points(geom, mat);
scene.add(points);

var clock = new THREE.Clock();

renderer.setAnimationLoop(() => {
  uniforms.time.value = clock.getElapsedTime();
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
});
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not change state in a shader. vertex shaders only output is `gl_Position` (to generate points/lines/triangles) and varyings that get passed to the fragment shader. Fragment shader's only output is `gl_FragColor` (in general). So trying to change `pos.y` will do nothing. The moment the shader exits your change is forgotten.

For your particle code though you could make the position a repeating function of the time

```
       const float duration = 5.0;
       float t = fract(elapsedTime / duration);
       pos.y = mix(-100.0, 100.0, t);
```

Assuming elapsedTime is in seconds then pos.y will go from -100 to 100 over 5 seconds and repeat.

Note in this case all the particles will fall at the same time. You could add an attribute to give them each a different time offsets or you could work their position into your own formula. Related to that you might find [this article](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-drawing-without-data.html) useful.

You could also do the particle movement in JavaScript like [this example](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_points_dynamic.html) and [this one](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_points_waves.html), updating the positions in the Geometry (or better, BufferGeometry)

Yet another solution is to do the movement in a separate shader by storing the positions in a texture and updating them to a new texture. Then using that texture as input another set of shaders that draws particles.