# How to animate multiple sprites in one direction using one geometry in Three.js?

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to do something similar to [this example](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_points_sprites.html), except instead of having the snow flakes flutter about in all directions I'm trying to animate these sprites in only one direction, like having the snow flakes fall to the ground.

The example above was able to load multiple sprites into one geometry since it can vary the rotations of the points object:

```
particles.rotation.x = Math.random() * 6;
particles.rotation.y = Math.random() * 6;
particles.rotation.z = Math.random() * 6;
```

However, this won't work if you're animating all the points in one direction. In this case, would I have to create a new geometry for each sprite, or is there a more efficient way to do this using just one geometry?

Comment: For some ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60251055/4045502

Answer (score 0):

There are several options. Instead of rotating randomly, you could:

- Decrease the y position on each frame with `particles.position.y -= 0.01;`. When it crosses a certain threshold (For example: `y <= -100`), move them back up to the origin (`y = 100`). You'll have to stagger a few Sprite objects so you don't notice the jump.
- Rotate along the x-axis, so the spinning motion makes them go *down* when in front of the camera.
  Since the snowflakes will spin *up* on the opposite side, you could use [some fog](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=fog#webgl_geometry_terrain) to hide the far side, and give it a more wintry feel.
- Animating [via custom shaders](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_buffergeometry_instancing), although this is much more complex if you don't know GLSL shader code.